# Can't Connect Node.js Thrift Client to Python Thrift Server

Tags: python, node.js, thrift

I'm trying to connect a nodejs thrift client to a python thrift server.

The python server is a multiplexed thrift server and works flawlessly with a python client.

Now I'm trying to add a node client to the game but so far I had no luck connecting it to the server.

```
var thrift = require('thrift')
var transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport;
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;


var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 8080, {
      transport : thrift.TBufferedTransport,
      protocol : thrift.TBinaryProtocol
});

connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

...
..
.
```

It keeps failing at creating a connection and I'm getting the error message

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
  at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
  at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080 }
```

I tested creating a connection between a node client and node server which worked without problems as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I set up a minimal working example which threw the same error as well.

After checking with 
`nv -v localhost 8080` I was presented with a "connection refused" error as well.
Following change solved my issue:

Change (**server.py**)

```
    transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=8080)
```

to

```
    transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(host="127.0.0.1",port=8080)
```